# Swapping between views within a view

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok guys, let me preface by saying I'm an extreme novice when it comes to iOS development, so please bear with me. So I'm using xcode 4.2/ios5/storyboard. What I'd like to create is a app like interface(just for practice and learning) that will allow me to swipe between views(I'm guessing within a view) and also use tabbed navigation at the bottom. so i'll try and draw it  rudimentary.

```
View 1 - view 1a
       - view 1b
       - view 1c

View 2

View 3 - view 3a
       - view 3b
       - view 3c
```

What I'd like to do is use the tabbed navigation to switch between views 1 2 and 3 but swiped between 1a,b,c and 3a,b,c. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on which each tab have a `UINaviagtionController` in it so you can swipe your views.
(Except for View 2, that could be a simple `UIViewController`).

Comment: `UINavigationController` does not provide swiping gestures to push and pop view controllers...

Comment: @MarkAdams no, but it's a `UIResponder` subClass, so you can listen with a GestureRecognizer for gestures you want and act accordingly to. The `UINavigationController` have push and pop capability.